# SUDS headers ignored when adding CustomTransport

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, soap, content-type, suds

I am trying to consume a web service with subs where I want to ignore the certificate checking since I am using a self signed certificate.

I found the way how to do this here:
[Bypass SSL when I'm using SUDS for consume web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327368/bypass-ssl-when-im-using-suds-for-consume-web-service/37331984)

The CustomTransport class is copied exactly the same as in the answer.

But I am getting error:
Exception: (415, u"Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.")

Even tho I am setting content type to soap in headers:

```
aHeader = {
    "Content-Type" : 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8',
    "SOAPAction": "",
}

client = Client(wsdl, transport=CustomTransport(), headers=aHeader)
```

I can't find a reason why this is happening, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Ignored because of the CustomTransport, so to make this work you need to put the headers inside customtransport like so:

```
client = Client(wsdl, transport=CustomTransport(headers=aHeader))
```